# Moving namespace attributes from the XML to Top

Tags: c#, xml, linq, wsdl, linq-to-xml

Hello friends I m having following type of XML

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="p1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
  <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <sp:Body />
  </sp:SignedParts>
</wsp:Policy>
```

But I want to convert it into following format

```
<wsdl:definitions
xmlns:sp=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy
xmlns:wsp=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy
xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="p1"  >
 <sp:SignedParts>
 <sp:Body />
 </sp:SignedParts>
 </wsp:Policy>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can you please tell how to do this either through LINQ or any other API

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string GetPolicy()
        {
            XDocument wsdlDocument = XDocument.Load(_wsdlPath);

            XName operationElementName = XName.Get("operation", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/");
            XName policyReferenceElementName = XName.Get("PolicyReference", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy");
            XName policyElementName = XName.Get("Policy", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy");
            XName idAttributeName = XName.Get("Id", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

            var operationPolicy = from operation in wsdlDocument.Descendants(operationElementName)
                                  where operation.Attribute("name").Value == _operationSelected
                                  from policyReference in operation.Descendants(policyReferenceElementName)
                                  where policyReference.Attribute("URI").Value.StartsWith("#")
                                  let uri = policyReference.Attribute("URI").Value.Substring(1)
                                  from policy in wsdlDocument.Descendants(policyElementName)
                                  where policy.Attribute(idAttributeName).Value == uri            
                                  select policy.ToString();

            #region Removing Embedded Namespaces
            string temp = operationPolicy.FirstOrDefault();
            if (temp.Contains(Constants.WSPolicyNsURI.XMLNS_SP) || temp.Contains(Constants.WSPolicyNsURI.XMLNS_WSP) || temp.Contains(Constants.WSPolicyNsURI.XMLNS_WSU))
            {
                temp = temp.Replace(Constants.WSPolicyNsURI.XMLNS_SP, String.Empty);
                temp = temp.Replace(Constants.WSPolicyNsURI.XMLNS_WSP, String.Empty);
                temp = temp.Replace(Constants.WSPolicyNsURI.XMLNS_WSU, String.Empty);
            }

            #endregion
            return temp;
        }
```